# Скрипт js по внешней ссылке не работает

Tags: javascript

Не работает скрипт при подключении по внешней ссылке . Подскажите пжлст как подключить правильно функцию fun1 из файла script.js.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="rus">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>BANK</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer>
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td >Сумма пополнения
                        </td>

                        <td><input id="summa" type="text">
                        </td>

                        <td><input  id="begunok" type="range" min="1000" max="3000000" step="1"  oninput="fun1()">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

```
<script>
                            function fun1() {
                                 var rng2=document.getElementById('begunok'); 
                                      var summa=document.getElementById('summa'); 
                                      summa.value=rng2.value;
                                      }
</script>
```

Comment: я не уверен, что в подключаемом файле должны быть какие-то html тэги, я имею в виду `<script>`

Comment: @splash58 Я уверен, что их там быть не должно

Answer (score 1):

в файле script.js удалите теги script или это автоматически в сообщение тут вставилось?

Answer (score -1):

Вы подключаете скрипт до отрисовки DOM. Один из вариантов исправления:

1. ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       //тут код
   })
   ```
2. Подключить скрипт перед `</body>`

Comment: *Вы подключаете скрипт до отрисовки DOM* И что ?..

Comment: под "//тут код" подразумевается код всей страницы html или подключение скрипта       
   <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer>
    </script>

Comment: по 2-му пункту скрипт подключен у меня перед body

Comment: Перед закрывающимся тегом body, а не в head.

Comment: //тут код -- в смысле код JS

Comment: При подключении скрипт не обращается к элементам DOM. А функция вызывается уже после формирования дерева

Comment: <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 src="script.js"
 });
 </script>

Comment: так не работает

Comment: `<script> $(document).ready(function(){ src="script.js" }); </script>` - господи, что ето ? идите читайте про HTML, js все с самого начала...